# crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am pretty new to programming and also to Flutter, so please excuse me if my question is silly. I am trying to push Skip button to the bottom left corner of the screen. But the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` code doesn't work. How could I do this the right way so it can adapt to all screen formats properly? The problematic part is at the bottom of the entire code. Thank you in advance!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 30),
            width: 230,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            child: Image.asset('images/logo1.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 30),
            child: Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 30),
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(
              'E-mail',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black54),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(7),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 15),
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Text(
              'Password',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black54),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(7),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 15),
            child: MaterialButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              ),
              height: 50.0,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: Text(
                "Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () => {},
              splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: Center(
              child: TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Forgot your password?',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Skip',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mobile Display

[image: Mobile Display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Row()`. Add `alignment: Alignment.centerRight,` to your `Container`.

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Skip',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried it just like that with only 'alignment: Alignment.bottomleft'. But the skip button doesn't move to the bottom of the screen for some reason.

The reason why I used Row widget was to create another TextButton parallel to our Skip button.

Comment: `Expanded(child: Container()),` Add this code above to the last `Container`

Comment: Now it works. I can't thank you enough Kamal! The program had to restart for some reason. I guess sometimes android studio crashes. Now I will try doing same at the bottom but to the other side.

Comment: When I apply the same code again for the bottom right, our Skip button on the bottom left goes up. It's because we have no Row. How could we fix this?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot and code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spacer` widget before `Row`. By default, row children will start from left.

```dart
 ///others widgets 
 const Spacer(), /// just add this
 Row(....
```

More about [Spacer widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

To change the position for Row children horizontally
you need to use mainAxisAlignment property

mainAxisAlignment property:
How the children should be placed along the main axis.
For example, MainAxisAlignment.start, the default, places the children at the start (i.e., the left for a Row or the top for a Column) of the main axis.

source flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/mainAxisAlignment.html